# how to find which application (client) id generated a specific access token - microsoft graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Let's say there are several valid access tokens from microsoft azure, all for a single user but generated using different applications and let's say their scopes are openid.

All tokens are valid, not expired and genuine. What I need is to differentiate them using which application (client) id generated every single one of them.

Is it possible to get this info?

Or at least if I have three application (client) ids and I'll send a request to an endpoint with access token and client id and check if it gives error or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every application has its own `Application ID` and it will always be unique.

So, you can decrypt the token into JWT format, and you can find `appid` claim which is nothing but the value of your Application ID.

Comment: Oh my God, how come I haven't seen it. I think I am way too tired